# table of contents, long table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

My issue is that in the table of contents it shows up as table table 4.1 instead of table 4.1. If anyone knows how to solve this issue, I'd be really thankful.

[image]

Here is my code, I had to delete the words and insert A, B, and X instead.

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5cm}|p{13.5cm}|}
\caption[A Review of X]{A Review of X}
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{A Review of X}
\endhead
\hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
A & B \\\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: We need a full (but minima) code that generates a list of tables like that. List of Table does not prefix entries with the word `Table` by default, thus it is important you provide code others can copy and test as is.

Comment: %% List of tables
\ifthenelse{\equal{\Langue}{english}}{
 \renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
}{
 \renewcommand\listtablename{LISTE DES TABLEAUX}
}\listoftables
%%
%% Liste des figures
%% List of figures
\ifthenelse{\equal{\Langue}{english}}{
 \renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES} }{
 \renewcommand\listfigurename{LISTE DES FIGURES}
}\listoffigures
}
\include{4-Sigles_Abrev}      
\ifthenelse{\equal{\AnnexesPresentes}{O}}{\listofappendices}{}
\mainmatter
\include{10-Empirical Test Results}           %
%\backmatter

Comment: do not add code in comments. Edit your question. And ensure that other can compile your code to reproduce the problem! Test it by copying your example in a new document in an empty folder and then compile.

Comment: I have too many codes and they are really confusing, I do not know what is relevant. But I do not have the issue with an other tables, just if I use the command long table, which I included in my preamble with \usepackage{amsmath,color,soulutf8,longtable,colortbl,setspace,xspace,url,pdflscape,cite}

Comment: The request is straight forward. Please provide a code that is compilable for us to try and reproduce your output. Here is why a MWE is important https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: you could delete all the `A & B \\\hline` lines as thy are unrelated to the caption but you need to show an example of the problem. All you have shown is you have some code that you have not shown whch incorrectly redefines the caption handling. It is impossible to even guess an answer with so little information